# twisted logging to screen(stdout) not working

Tags: python, logging, twisted

i have this small program [taken from here](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.3.0/core/howto/logger.html#usage-for-emitting-applications)

```
from twisted.logger import Logger
log = Logger()

def handleData(data):
    log.debug("Got data: {data!r}.", data=data)

handleData({'a':20})
```

This does not prints anything to the screen .why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The default python logger is set to WARN level, so DEBUG messages are suppressed. You can make that code work like -

```
import logging
from twisted.logger import Logger
log = Logger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def handleData(data):
    log.debug("Got data: {data!r}.", data=data)

handleData({'a':20})
```

Comment: i tried that but it gives `AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'setLevel'`

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out from here https://github.com/moira-alert/worker/blob/master/moira/logs.py:

```
import logging
from twisted.logger import Logger, LogLevel
import sys


from twisted.logger import globalLogPublisher
from twisted.logger import textFileLogObserver
from twisted.logger import FilteringLogObserver, LogLevelFilterPredicate, LogLevel



log = Logger()


level = LogLevel.debug
predicate = LogLevelFilterPredicate(defaultLogLevel=level)
observer = FilteringLogObserver(textFileLogObserver(sys.stdout), [predicate])
observer._encoding = "utf-8"
globalLogPublisher.addObserver(observer)
log.info("Start logging with {l}", l=level)

def handleData(data):
    log.debug("Got data: {data!r}.", data=data)

handleData({'a':20})
```

Is there any simpler way . it seems overly complicated just to set log level.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add observer for your logger object.
here is a simple observer that print the log to stdout

```
 import sys
 from twisted.logger import Logger, eventAsText, FileLogObserver

 log = Logger()
 log.observer.addObserver(FileLogObserver(sys.stdout, lambda e: eventAsText(e) + "\n"))

 someData = 2
 log.debug("Got data: {data!r}", data=someData)
```