# logging with twisted not printing to the screen

Tags: python, twisted

Question is somewhat related to this. [twisted logging to screen(stdout) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657962/twisted-logging-to-screenstdout-not-working/57658624#57658624)

I want to put logs on screen using [twisted logger](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.3.0/core/howto/logger.html#usage-for-emitting-applications). it works when a string is passed to the log methods but when python objects are passed as mentioned in the linked document it does not works(log statement at last line in code below).

```
import logging
from twisted.logger import Logger, LogLevel
import sys

from twisted.logger import globalLogPublisher
from twisted.logger import textFileLogObserver
from twisted.logger import FilteringLogObserver, LogLevelFilterPredicate, LogLevel

log = Logger()

level = LogLevel.debug
predicate = LogLevelFilterPredicate(defaultLogLevel=level)
observer = FilteringLogObserver(textFileLogObserver(sys.stdout), [predicate])
globalLogPublisher.addObserver(observer)

#---------> This works
log.info("Start logging with {l}", l=level)

#---------> This does not
log.debug(data=log)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/twisted-16.3.0/twisted/logger/_logger.py
Both `.debug` and `.info` call the the same `def emit(self, level, format=None, **kwargs)`

in case of info it's `self.emit(LogLevel.info, format, **kwargs)` and debug calls `self.emit(LogLevel.debug, format, **kwargs)`

So if you want your log.debug work properly you should stick to the format and call it somewhat like:

```
log.debug('debug with {obj}', obj=log)
```

Comment: according to signature of `emit()` when format is not passed its value is defaulted to `None` so ` log.debug(obj=log)` should work. also from this document https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.2.0/core/howto/logger.html

Comment: sure, format can be `None` and emit will defintely run. But then it's passed to observer by calling `self.observer(event)` where event is a dict with 'log_format=format' which is None. Then take a look at `def _formatEvent(event):` in `_format.py` there's  `if format is None: return u""` It will print an empty string.